# How to remove a user control programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a situation where the following control is registered after the DOCTYPE but before the `<head>`

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/GoogleScriptControl.ascx" TagName="ScriptControl" TagPrefix="UC" %>
```

And then later called in the `<body>` of my page.

```
<UC:ScriptControl ID="ucScriptControl" runat="server" />
```

Is there a way to programmatically remove or prevent this UC from being loaded? I read that this should be done in the Page_Init.  I tried using

```
ucScriptControl.Dispose()
```

But had no luck.

Comment: Are you try Page.Controls.Remove(yourControl);?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - using  `Remove` method

```
var yourControl = (GoogleScriptControl)Page.FindControl("ucScriptControl")
this.Controls.Remove(yourControl );
```

or this code change visibility

```
yourControl.Visible = false;
```